# Airflow does not launch my dags (activate a python environment and launch a python script)

Tags: python, airflow

I would like to schedule a Python job to launch it every 15 minutes. I have already used airflow and haven't met any issues before. 
I created a dag with a start date earlier today, a frequency of 15 minutes and two tasks which consist of activating a virtual Python environment and then launch a python script.

However, my dags do not execute itself so I started a web server to check its status and nothing happened. I, therefore, tried to launch it externally using the trigger_dag command but its status remain on running. I really do not understand what the problem is, any help would be appreciated. I attach two screenshots of the Airflow webserver which show the problem.

[image]

[image]

Edit : added the dags.py file, here is the definition of my dags :

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator


default_args = {
    'owner': 'test',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017,10,13,0,0,0,0),
    'email': ['test@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    #'end_date': datetime(2017, 9, 23),
}

dag = DAG('dbscan_integ', default_args=default_args)


t_dbscan = BashOperator(
    task_id='job_batch_dbscan',
        bash_command='/home/test/Documents/git_repo/analyser/algo_integ/integration_dbscan/python main_algo.py',
dag=dag)


t_virtual_dbscan = BashOperator(
    task_id='virtual_dbscan',
    bash_command='source activate integdb',
    dag=dag)
t_dbscan.set_upstream(t_virtual_dbscan)
```

Comment: It will help if you also share the relevant code snippets from your DAG. This can happen if you miss to assign task to the DAG while defining them.

Comment: @Him I added the code of my dags however I think my tasks are correctly assigned to the tasks thanks to the parameter dag=dag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is stupid, but do you have the scheduler and worker up and running?

---

Edit 1:

Ok, I think the reason is that you do not have schedule_interval in your dag, instead you give timedelta(minutes=15) to retry_delay.

Comment: This is not the schedule_interval I noticed that and fixed it. I did not understand that the scheduler had to be run separately I will test that on monday. Thank you very much